# Subequations and align: ERROR: Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here?

Tags: align, labels, subequations, tags

I have an issue with my optimization problem. It is given in the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

    \begin{document}

        \begin{subequations}
            \label{pb:1} %\tag{P1} --> HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            \begin{align}
                & {\underset{\mathbf{ x }}{\text{maximize}}}
                & & \sum_{i=1}^nv_ix_i\label{obj:1}\tag{P1a}\\
                & \text{subject to}
                & &  \sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_{i}\leqslant W,\label{c:1}\tag{P1b}\\
                & & & x_{ i }\in\{0, 1\}, \forall i=1\ldots,n.\label{c:1}\tag{P1c}
          \end{align}
       \end{subequations}

       Problem~\eqref{pb:1} is a binary programming problem.


    \end{document}
```

When I remove the `\tag{P1}`, I got no errors. How to fix this?

This problem comes when trying to label the problem as `(P1)`, `(P1a)`, etc. So I find that I should add the `\tag` but when I did this the only way I can reference `(P1)` is by calling it each time `(P1)`. For example if I write `\eqref{pb:1}` I will get:

[image]

In the above figure, I would like to replace `(1)` by `(P1)` whenever I call `\eqref{pb:1}`. That's why I added `\tag` after the `subequations`.

However, if I remove the tags, I get:

[image]

but that's not what I want.

Comment: `\tag` can only be used inside a math display , what do you want it to do in that position?

Comment: also why are you numbering by hand with `\tag` on each line???, it defeats the whole purpose of  the `subequations` environment.

Comment: When I would like to reference `P1`, I write `\eqref{pb:1}` but it produces a number like `(1)`.  I would like to call it `(P1)` instead. Thanks.

Comment: Because I would like to name the problem as `(P1)`, `(P1a)`, etc. not `(1)`, `(1a)`, etc.

Comment: You have not got an equation 1 normally you would have an `equation` which is numbered say 2 then a bunch of equations inside `subequations` and they will _automatically_ be numbered 2.1, 2.2, ...

Comment: Sure but the _only_ thing `subequations` does is change the default numbering and you are not numbering the equations at all.  It would be better to use automatic numbering and just specify that the equation counter is prefixed by P

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: If I remove the `subequations` and keep `align` alone, it says ` Multiple \label's: label 'pb:1' will be lost.`

Comment: no only if you put the label into align, where there is already a label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can use independent counters for equations and problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb} % not needed with newtxmath
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\maximize}{%
  \mathopen{}\operatorname*{maximize}%
}
\newcommand{\subjto}{\textup{subject to}}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{save@equation}
\newcounter{save@problem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{problem}
 {\setcounter{problem}{\value{save@problem}}%
  \setcounter{save@equation}{\value{equation}}%
  \let\c@equation\c@problem
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{P\arabic{equation}}%
  \subequations
  }
 {\endsubequations
  \setcounter{save@problem}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{save@equation}}%
 }

\begin{document}

Some text and an equation
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
Some other text before the problem
\begin{problem}\label{pb:1}
\begin{alignat}{2}
& \maximize_{\mathbf{x}}
  &\qquad & \sum_{i=1}^nv_ix_i\label{obj:1}\\
& \text{subject to}
  & &  \sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_{i}\leqslant W,\label{b:1}\\
  & & & x_{ i }\in\{0, 1\}, \forall i=1\ldots,n.\label{c:1}
\end{alignat}
\end{problem}
Problem~\eqref{pb:1} is a binary programming problem. And
another equation
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
And another problem
\begin{problem}\label{pb:2}
\begin{alignat}{2}
& \maximize_{\mathbf{x}}
  &\qquad & \sum_{i=1}^nv_ix_i\label{obj:2}\\
& \text{subject to}
  & &  \sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_{i}\leqslant W,\label{b:2}\\
  & & & x_{ i }\in\{0, 1\}, \forall i=1\ldots,n.\label{c:2}
\end{alignat}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Just a quick question: If I want to split a constraint (say the last one) in two lines using this code, should I do `\\ & & & last constraint\\ & & & continued constraint`. I did this but I am trying to shift the `continued constraint` to the right a little. So I did `\\ & & & last constraint\\ & & & \quad\quad\quad\quad continued constraint` but (1) the code looks ugly and (2) it doesn't shift further as I add more `\quad`.

Comment: @Riebuoz That's a completely different question.

Comment: Is this possible in beamer?

Comment: @Ribz Numbered equations in beamer should be an exception: the audience won't remember what's equation 3 after just a few slides

Answer (score 2):

Simply redefine `\theequation`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\renewcommand*{\theequation}{P\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \label{pb:1}
  \begin{align}
    & {\underset{\mathbf{ x }}{\text{maximize}}}
    & & \sum_{i=1}^nv_ix_i\label{obj:1}\\
    & \text{subject to}
    & &  \sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_{i}\leqslant W,\label{c:1}\\
    & & & x_{ i }\in\{0, 1\}, \forall i=1\ldots,n.\label{c:2}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

Problem~\eqref{pb:1} is a binary programming problem.

\end{document}
```

[image: P1a-P1c]

If you need different prefixes you can use something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\theequationprefix\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand*{\theequationprefix}{}
\newcommand*{\equationprefix}[2][0]{%
  \renewcommand*{\theequationprefix}{#2}% Change the prefix
  \setcounter{equation}{#1}% reset the counter to optional argument
}

\begin{document}

\equationprefix{P}% must be before subequation!
\begin{subequations}
  \label{pb:1}
  \begin{align}
    & {\underset{\mathbf{ x }}{\text{maximize}}}
    & & \sum_{i=1}^nv_ix_i\label{obj:1}\\
    & \text{subject to}
    & &  \sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_{i}\leqslant W,\label{c:1}\\
    & & & x_{ i }\in\{0, 1\}, \forall i=1\ldots,n.\label{c:2}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

Problem~\eqref{pb:1} is a binary programming problem.

\equationprefix{}% no prefix
\begin{align}
  x=y\label{noprefix}
\end{align}
Equation~\eqref{noprefix}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I have many other equations in my document, does this change all my `\eqref{x}` to `(Px)`? I mean later in my document, I have an equation called `(20)`, will this be called `(P20)` if I call `\eqref{20}`?

Comment: and there are two c:1 labels.

Comment: @Riebuoz: Sure. If you want different prefixes you have to redefine `\theequation` several times or define a markup command to change the prefix.

Comment: How to define it only once or twice? (For some specific equations.)