# How to split a long constraint in this optimization problem?

Tags: alignat, split

I have an optimization problem that has a long constraint. So, I would like to split it. Obviously, I search how to split long equation but I did not find my answer as the problem is related to how I format my optimization problem. Especially, I write it based on [the answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348060/82714) of my previous question. Below I give the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\maximize}{%
  \mathopen{}\operatorname*{maximize}%
}
\newcommand{\subjto}{\textup{subject to}}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{save@equation}
\newcounter{save@problem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{problem}
{\setcounter{problem}{\value{save@problem}}%
  \setcounter{save@equation}{\value{equation}}%
  \let\c@equation\c@problem
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{P\arabic{equation}}%
  \subequations
}
{\endsubequations
  \setcounter{save@problem}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{save@equation}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}\label{pb:2}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    & \maximize_{\mathbf{x}}
    &\qquad & \sum_{i=1}^nv_ix_i\label{obj:2}\\
    & \text{subject to}
    & &  \sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_{i}\leqslant W,\label{c:1}\\
    & & & \left(c_1+c_2+\ldots+c_n\right)x_ix_j\leqslant C,\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}, j\in\{1,\ldots,n\},\label{c:2}\\
    & & & x_{ i }\in\{0, 1\}, \forall i=1\ldots,n.\label{c:3}
  \end{alignat}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following:

[image]

Now, constraint (P1c) is long (as I actually work with double column paper). I would like to split it just after `C,`. I am asking how to split it according to my code? Should I change the `alignat` to `split` or something?

I tried to do it with:

1. `\\`. Here I am getting something ugly, like:

   `& & & \left(c_1+c_2+\ldots+c_n\right)x_ix_j\leqslant C,\\ 
   \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}, j\in\{1,\ldots,n\},\label{c:2}\\`[image]
2. `\\ & & &` and `\quad`. Here it is better but still not enough, like:

   `& & & \left(c_1+c_2+\ldots+c_n\right)x_ix_j\leqslant C,\\ 
   & & &\quad\quad\quad\quad \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}, j\in\{1,\ldots,n\},\label{c:2}\\`[image]

   But this won't work as I add more `\quad`.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unfortunate that people don't upvote well-rounded questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, if I've well understood what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\maximize}{%
  \mathopen{}\operatorname*{maximize}%
}
\newcommand{\subjto}{\textup{subject to}}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{save@equation}
\newcounter{save@problem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{problem}
{\setcounter{problem}{\value{save@problem}}%
  \setcounter{save@equation}{\value{equation}}%
  \let\c@equation\c@problem
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{P\arabic{equation}}%
  \subequations
}
{\endsubequations
  \setcounter{save@problem}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{save@equation}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}\label{pb:2}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    & \maximize_{\mathbf{x}}
    &\qquad & \sum_{i=1}^nv_ix_i\label{obj:2}\\
    & \text{subject to}
    & & \sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_{i}\leqslant W,\label{c:1}\\
    & & &\!\begin{aligned} (c_1 +c_2 +\dots+c_n&)x_ix_j\leqslant C,\\ & \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}, j\in\{1,\ldots,n\},
    \end{aligned}\label{c:2}\\
    & & & x_{ i }\in\{0, 1\},\; \forall i=1\ldots,n.\label{c:3}
  \end{alignat}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I shift (P1c) (the second part of (P1c)) to the right more?

Comment: Oh! yes, very easily: move the `&` at the line above a little more to the right. See my updated answer: I now have `&)`.